# Does SubSonic run under Mono?

Tags: subsonic, mono, monodevelop

Has anyone deployed SubSonic on Mono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be of user - In the mingle of the question theres somone stating he has it running under mono and the steps you need to take

http://forums.subsonicproject.com/t/2761.aspx

http://blog.wekeroad.com/subsonic/SubSonic-Monos-The-New-Black/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanting to bump the question. I managed to get partial PostgreSQL support for mono. I had to modify quite a lot of code to do it(and that code is no longer in my possession, ie proprietary) but it shouldn't be too hard. I did it with 2.6. So I got it to generate code files for the databases and such(ActiveRecord) but the problem came when I tried to use Linq. Linq was completely broken for me, and apparently Mono had only recently declared it's Linq status to be "beta". You may have better luck trying to port it now, but there doesn't seem to be any official support of Mono, sadly.